# Is there an object with the properties of the Minkowski plane?

Tags: geometry

Maybe I have it all wrong and $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ has nothing to do with geometry and is merely called "plane" by Wikipedia because it's a system of pairs of numbers, but if it is possible to draw triangles and find areas and angles on $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$, what object would have its behaviors? What I mean is, we can see the properties of the euclidean plane like its triangles' angles summing to 180 degrees on a piece of paper, is there a sheet or solid that has the properties of the Minkowski plane, if "properties of geometry on the Minkowski plane" even makes sense?

Comment: See `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Geometry` and maybe `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model`

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a sheet or solid that has the properties of the Minkowski plane

The typical approach is to keep your sheet of paper, but swap your ruler and protractor, figuratively speaking. That is you keep the usual coordinates (and keep calling it a plane) but you redefine your concepts of distance and angle measurement.

Unfortunately it's not as simple as swapping an inch-based ruler for a metric one. The concepts are fundamentally different, and physically implementing any suitable measurement tools would be a real engineering challenge. Computers can provide virtual versions of such tools far more easily.

For example, points on the same light ray would be at distance zero from one another. Some squared distances would be positive while others are negative, so when you take the square roots, some of the distances will be purely imaginary numbers.

The angle measurement will be hyperbolic, instead of the elliptic angle measurement you're used to. That means that angles don't come full circle. In Euclidean geometry, if you add a small angle over and over again you eventually end up close to where you started. In the Minkowski plane you get closer and closer to the light cone, without ever crossing it. No way to get back to where you started by turning in the same direction long enough. And no, you shouldn't expect angles to sum to $180°$.

Richter-Gebert's *Perspectives on Projective Geometry* has section 20.6 discussing various Cayley-Klein geometries. Type VI in that list is what you're talking about, and he's using the terms *Minkowski geometry* and *pseudo-Euclidean geometry*. There also is an illustration of an incidence theorem using pseudo-Euclidean circles, which actually are hyperbolas in the plane.

Actually circles are one of the most interesting concepts to consider here. Straight lines remain straight lines, so triangles are kind of boring unless you need to compute angles, at which point it becomes tedious but not really insightful. Seeing hyperbolas (with the same asymptote directions matching the light cone) play the role of circles should give you a much better intuition about what kind of world you're in.

For example take a point and a Minkowski circle around it. There will be lines through the point that don't intersect the hyperbola representing that circle. So there are some directions where you never encounter a point that has a distance from the starting point which matches the radius of the “circle”. Time-like and space-like directions are fundamentally different, and you can't wait for a duration of five meters to pass, or cut a rope to a length of two minutes. One of these units will be real, the other imaginary.

Comments have already provided some useful reading material on Wikipedia:

- [Minkowski space § Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Geometry)
- [Hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) if you do hyperbolic geometry in Minkowski space, although I'd argue you need one more dimension for this to be useful
- [Pseudo-Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space)

And if you want to challenge your imagination, you could read *Dichronauts* by Greg Egan, a novel set in a Minkowski space.